# Cant get 'Show zero as' to work in Report Builder 3.0

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report containing a tablix. Some of the fields in the tablix contain no value upon report creation. I want to show '0.00' as a default in these fields.

I have looked at textbox properties > Number > "Show zero as" but no matter what I cant get them to show.

I have to admit that I'm a SSRS newbie so I might have overlooked something. I googled a bit around and found something about IF statements in the expression, but cant quite figure it out.

The table data in the tablix is floating-point numbers.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the SQL if possible otherwise Chris Latta's answer is best.

For example if you use oracle you should use the `nvl(v1, 0)` function, or the `isnull(v1, 0)` for MS SQL. Keeping it in the query will reduce required processing.

Comment: Thank you both - I went with glh's option. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

The problem sounds like they are `Null`, not zero. Try using an expression like this:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!MyField.Value), 0, Fields!MyField.Value)
```

So when it is nothing (that is, `Null`), you get zero, otherwise you get the field value.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use the literal value of zero to get this to work.

```
=IIf(Sum(Fields!NewCount.Value) = 0, "0", Sum(Fields!NewCount.Value))
```

Answer (score -1):

add zero to the expression:

```
=Sum(Fields!NewCount.Value) + 0
```